# Rendering doesn't work after switching on the denoiser

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, denoise

Rendered the animation without denoising before and it was fine.
but i wanted to denoise it in the composite with nodes.
but when i rendered it it overrided the previous animation, plus nothing renders at all even image or animation.

Thank You.[image]

Comment: Hi Bill, in it's current state this question is impossible to answer. Please provide further information: Which type of denoiser are you using (Intel or the built in solution)? Does the image render again, when you turn denoising off? What are your render settings? How does your hardware look like?

Comment: The built in one. No the image or animation never renders ever, just black even if denoising is off. It rendered nicely earlier (2 hour render on cycles 150 frames btw) but when i tried to denoise w/ nodes in the compositing tab it renders blackness in like a second.

Comment: FYI the denoising node in the compositor is not the built in denoiser. That node is called the Intel-AI-Denoiser.